# how to set size and position of UIButton's image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

UIButton, how to set size and position of background image ?

e.g how to change size and position the image to be on top of the `UIButton`

EDIT: issue fixed by using `setImageEdgeInsets:` e.g:

```
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -image.size.width, 0, 0)];
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, button.titleLabel.bounds.size.width, 0, 0)];
```

Comment: what you want to modify?

Comment: I believe you're looking for UIButton's image property `[myButton setImage:<#(UIImage *)#> forState:<#(UIControlState)#>];`

Comment: I wanna modify le size of the image background without resizing the button frame, cause if I add a subview on it, i wont have the animation on touch

Comment: That's what the 'forState' is for, so you can change the image on touch.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no property like that, but in my opinion you will have to scale the image according to the size of the `UIButton`.

for example you can use this code

```
  UIImage *resultImage = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(button.frame.size.height,button.frame.size.width) : sourchImage];
```

method for scaling

```
- (UIImage*)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize:(UIImage *)srcimage
{
    UIImage *sourceImage = srcimage;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;        
    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) 
    {
        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor > heightFactor) 
            scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width
        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image
        if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        }
        else 
            if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
            }
    }       

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); // this will crop

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    if(newImage == nil) 
        NSLog(@"could not scale image");

    //pop the context to get back to the default
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to scale an image, do it, but you should resize it before using it. Resizing it at run time will just lose CPU cycles.

This is the category I'm using to scale an image :

UIImage+Extra.h

```
@interface UIImage (Extras)
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize;
@end;
```

UIImage+Extra.m

```
@implementation UIImage (Extras)

- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize {

UIImage *sourceImage = self;
UIImage *newImage = nil;

CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize)) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) 
                scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
                scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
                thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
        } else if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
                thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
}


// this is actually the interesting part:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

[sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


return newImage ;
}

@end
```

You can use it to the size you want. Like :

```
[self.itemImageButton setImage:[stretchImage imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:CGSizeMake(20,20)]];
```